# SQL DIFFERENCE function with names bringing too many results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, difference

I have a function that uses the [SQL DIFFERENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) function to see if the name of a client is similar to a client already in the database

```
SELECT ID FROM People p
WHERE DIFFERENCE(p.FullName, @fullName) = 4
```

Being @fullname a variable passed to the function. The issue I'm having is that if I pass "pedro sanchez" as a parameter, the query will bring me all the Peter's in the database, or if I enter "pablo sanchez", it'll bring record "PEOPLE'S CREDIT UNION".

As I understand the DIFFERENCE function should returns 4 when the two strings are almost identical, but the results I'm having say otherwise.

Is there a way to further specify the resemblance to the DIFFERENCE function, or maybe another approach in finding similar names ?

Answer (score 3):

`Difference()` is based on `soundex()`, which in turn -- to be frank -- is a lousy system for comparing strings. Let me add a caveat: it is pretty good for the purpose it was designed for, which is matching last names of people in English. You can read about the rules [here](http://www.archives.gov/research/census/soundex.html) and you can try it out [here](http://www.eogn.com/soundex/). Using the latter link, you can see that "Pedro" and "People" have the same code, P-140.

Soundex encodes the *consonants* and basically the first four matching consonants the list it cares about. (Some languages, such as Hawaiian and other Polynesian languages are rather light in consonants. One assumes the designers were not thinking about names in such languages.)

When you are looking for proximity among written strings, [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is a common metric. Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have this functionality built-in, but you can easily find implementations on the web. For most real applications, Levenshtein distance is too slow. Happily, the functionality of the full text search component is usually sufficient for most purposes.